# MyMoney, how to import Quicken QDF files

Tags: kmymoney

Where can I find help with MyMoney? Specifically about importing Quicken QDF files/backups.

I'm looking for a user group, but can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here. First, there is the KMyMoney forum over at [KDE.org:](http://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=69&sid=5e93fd2c027e58108bbfb2398afd2ae1). Second, you can ask over at the IRC channel "KMyMoney" over on Freenode.

My suggestion would be to try the forum first, as it is more active than the IRC channel. Good luck.